# Creating a react native new module in package.json

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to create a new module based on the following guide:

https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/

Near the last paragraph he saids just add a {"name": "@assets"} into the JSON file. I am unsure exactly how to write it, can anyone help?

Comment: Where is your package,json file

Comment: does it helped? @DaemonS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you plan to publish your package, the most important things in your
>   package.json are the name and version fields as they will be required.

so you are creating a new `package.json` and named it as `{"name": "@assets"}`. Now you are exposing your image dictionary `assets` as a module. And for accessing do this `Import Images from ‘@assets/images’;` in components. The new package.json should be inside you asset folder.

Comment: adding to the answer, I also had the hard time understanding the article. even after adding name` in` package.json, I got an error message. I resolved it by adding a `main` field in `package.json` with the value `images.js`. so my package.json looked like this: `{ "name": "@assets", "version": "1.0.0", "main": "images.js"}` I think name and main are the necessary fields though

Answer (score 0):

`{"name": "@assets"}` is just the name of the module that you will be using when importing.

So in this case the name of the module is `@assets`